# Spring Cloud could not resolve "${spring.util.timeout.sec:${SPRING_UTIL_TIMEOUT_SEC:1}}" when PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer is used

Tags: spring-cloud

So, I have a third party library that has the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` defined, like this:

```
@Bean
PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer libraryProperties() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer config = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    config.setLocations(new Resource[]{new ClassPathResource("library_config.properties")});
    config.setPlaceholderPrefix("$library{");
    config.setPlaceholderSuffix("}");
    config.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
    config.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
    return config;
}
```

whereas in my app I just use Spring Boot 2.1.0 autoconfig to configure everything.

The application runs fine if I remove Spring Cloud (client) by commenting out:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

but once I add that dependency, I got the following stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'compositeDiscoveryClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/client/discovery/composite/CompositeDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.class]: 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'compositeDiscoveryClient' parameter 0; 

nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.simple.SimpleDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration':
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'inet'; 

nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'inetUtils' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/commons/util/UtilAutoConfiguration.class]: 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'inetUtils' parameter 0; 

nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'inetUtilsProperties': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'timeoutSeconds'; 

nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: 
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${spring.util.timeout.sec:${SPRING_UTIL_TIMEOUT_SEC:1}}"
```

Which in the InetUtilsProperties class is defined as:

```
/**
 * Timeout, in seconds, for calculating hostname.
 */
@Value("${spring.util.timeout.sec:${SPRING_UTIL_TIMEOUT_SEC:1}}")
private int timeoutSeconds = 1;
```

Why is the `@Value` not being resolved with that `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`?

I have to mention though that, before using that library, Spring Cloud worked like a charm.

Can you guys help me out here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This custom `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` (resolve `$library{foo}`) overrides an auto-config one which helps to resolve `${foo}`.
Add this to your configuration and try again:

```
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
```